# Write in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am reading a `sql.txt` file and this is one section. What it does is create a table "Page":

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Page`;
CREATE TABLE `Page` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pageId` int(11) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pageId` (`pageId`)
)

--
-- Dumping data for table `Page`
--

LOCK TABLES `Page` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Page` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Page` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I have a few questions:

1. Is the `TABLES` a database name?
2. Does the `WRITE` load data to the table 'page'? If yes, where is the source of the data?
3. Does the lock mean first locking the database?

Comment: The `LOCK TABLES` command is explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html)

Comment: #1. No, It's Called Pages. #2. In this example, no. You have to input data manually in SSMS or through another thing like SSIS, an application or web front end for example.

Comment: Thank you, @EdGibbs & GabrielVa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. TABLES is not the database name. It means which table(s) to lock (in this case table 'Page').
2. WRITE means, the table is locked for writing into it.
3. It means locking the table, not the database.

Answer (score 0):

[`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) is a SQL command (see link for the documentation) that will apply a lock to the set of tables specified. In this case, it is only one table, `Page`:

```
LOCK TABLES `Page` WRITE;
```

In this case it would be two tables:

```
LOCK TABLES `Page`, `Book` WRITE;
```

The lock can have a 'type', which in this case is `WRITE`. That means no data can be written to the table while this lock is in place. This ensures that no updates overwrite what is being written before everything has been completed. This keeps the database table in a known state.

Note that you can still read from a table under a write lock. This means that reads will be nondeterministic as the data is being written.

SQL doesn't support locking the entire database (as far as I know). The above command will only lock the specified tables.